# readonly field assigned in constructor and also clearing it doesn't clear values

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, readonly

I have a readonly field like this

```
private readonly IManageSessionContext _manageSessionContext;

public ManageController(IManageSessionContext manageSessionContext)
{
      _manageSessionContext= manageSessionContext;
      //doing some operations
      _manageSessionContext.Clear();
}
```

Doesn't clear the session or object values of this read only field. Why? But when I place it before the return statement in Index View, it does clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not provided any of the code for your `Index` action however in your example you are calling `_manageSessionContext.Clear();` in your constructor.

The constructor is called when the class `ManageController` is created passing in the `IManageSessionContext` dependency. The constructor is always called first where you are first `Clear()`ing the `IManageSessionContext` (whatever that is).

My hunch is there is more work being done in the `IManageSessionContext` between the constructor of `ManageController` class being called and the return of your `Index` action method.

For example. Take the code snippet below

```
public class ManageController
{
    readonly IManageSessionContext _manageSessionContext;

    public ManageController(IManageSessionContext manageSessionContext)
    {
        _manageSessionContext = manageSessionContext;

        //some operations..
        _manageSessionContext.Clear();
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        _manageSessionContext.DoSomeWorkWithManagedContext();

        _manageSessionContext.Clear();

        return View();
    }

}
```

The code executes the constructor first `ManageController(IManageSessionContext manageSessionContext)` which eventually calls the `Clear()` method for the `IManageSessionContext`

Next the action `Index` executes, Index `DoSomeWorkWithManagedContext()` is called which changes the `IManageSessionContext` dependency. Then the `Index` method re-calls the `Clear` method.

Now in the chain would go

1. Constructor Called -> Clear's session
2. Index Method (action) called Does work in the session -> Clears session

As the constructor is executed **first** any additional work with the object will change the object thus requiring a `Clear` before closing the `Index` method.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Nico, sort of makes sense, your code is similar to my scenario

Comment: The only important thing to understand is the constructor is called first all the code in the constructor executed then the method (index). Therefore any calls made to the `_manageSessionContext` happen after the constructor is called. Put a break point at the last line of the constructor and the first line of your action. 100% of the time the constructor will be called before the method.

Comment: Actually, the difference is, when I call clear in Index method it clears and alternatively, if I ,move the logic from constructor to a function and not calling this function from constructor but from the index method, it still clears to value. It is only when I have all these logic inside constructor, it doesn't clears value. I want to know why. That was my question too

Comment: I agree, but I do not have any other calls to IManageSessionContext except in constructor. I am just using the values of that object that I assign in constructor. Then once I use, I am trying to clear the field in the constructor itself. Secondly, my index method doesn't have a body but just returns Index result